# Linux Kernel Headers are missing on EKS cluster

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, amazon-eks, ebpf

I have developed an eBPF code that needs to be compiled with kernel headers.
My code is working properly on top of AKS however on an EKS cluster I couldn't find the kernel headers.

The kernel version of my vms on EKS is: "5.4.117-58.216.amzn2.x86_64". 
Running "apt install linux-headers-$(uname -r)" result:
[image]

What is the right way to get kernel headers in case they don't exist in apt?

Answer (score 2):

You can find kernel headers for Amazon Linux 2 kernels by searching into their packages' SQLite databases.

In your case, following procedure too:

1. Download the mirror list

```sh
wget amazonlinux.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/2/extras/kernel-5.4/latest/x86_64/mirror.list
```

Notice that for other kernel versions you may want to substitute "extras/kernel-5.4/latest" with "core/latest" or "core/2.0".

It should contain one (or more) URL(s) like this one:

http://amazonlinux.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/2/extras/kernel-5.4/stable/x86_64/be95e4ca87d6c3b5eb71edeaded5b3b9b216d7cdd330d44f1489008dc4039789

2. Append the suffix `repodata/primary.sqlite.gz` to the URL(s) and download the SQLite database(s)

```sh
wget "$(head -1 mirror.list)/repodata/primary.sqlite.gz"
```

Notice the URL(s) may contain the placeholder "$basearch". If that's the case, substitute it with the target architecture (eg., x86_64).

3. Unarchive it

```sh
gzip -d primary.sqlite.gz
```

4. Query it for finding where to download your kernel-headers package.

```sh
sqlite3 primary.sqlite \
  "SELECT location_href FROM packages WHERE name LIKE 'kernel%' AND name NOT LIKE '%tools%' AND name NOT LIKE '%doc%' AND version='5.4.117' AND release='58.216.amzn2'" | \
  sed 's#\.\./##g'
```

You'll obtain these:

```
blobstore/e12d27ecb4df92edc6bf25936a732c93f55291f7c732b83f4f37dd2aeaad5dd4/kernel-headers-5.4.117-58.216.amzn2.x86_64.rpm
blobstore/248b2b078145c4cc7c925850fc56ec0e3f0da141fb1b269fd0c2ebadfd8d41cd/kernel-devel-5.4.117-58.216.amzn2.x86_64.rpm
blobstore/7d82d21a61fa03af4b3afd5fcf2309d5b6a1f5a01909a1b6190e8ddae8a67b89/kernel-5.4.117-58.216.amzn2.x86_64.rpm
```

5. Download the package you want by appending its segment to the initial base URL

Like so:

```sh
wget amazonlinux.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/blobstore/e12d27ecb4df92edc6bf25936a732c93f55291f7c732b83f4f37dd2aeaad5dd4/kernel-headers-5.4.117-58.216.amzn2.x86_64.rpm
```

A similar procedure can be used for Amazon Linux 1 kernel headers.

Comment: you can get the mirror url information inside `/etc/yum.repos.d/`. Note that there are a lot of variable inside the files which some of them can be found `/etc/yum/vars/`or you can execute `rpm --query --file --queryformat '%{VERSION}\n' /etc/system-release` to get all of them (ref: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/20226/402777).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's an ideal solution, but you could always download the kernel sources and install the headers from there.

```
$ git clone --depth 1 -b v5.4.117 \
        git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git
$ cd linux
# make headers_install
```

The headers you get from the stable branch are likely close enough to those of your kernel for your eBPF program to work. I don't know if there's a way to retrieve the header files used for building EKS' kernel.